# Why passing by value is sometimes better than passing by reference

Tags: pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, cpu-cache

It is a common fact that it is better in a certain circumstances to pass a parameter by reference to avoid costly copying. But recently I watched a Handmade Hero series where Casey said that if the object is not too complex sometimes it's better to pass it by value. I'm not too familiar with low-level details, but I assume it's connected with a cache. Could someone give more solid explanation of what's going on?

Comment: Hey I'm curious what episode he mentioned this in.

Here's an example of Casey going the opposite direction, going from passing a struct by value to passing by reference, and here he mentions that the only reason he did it the other way first was because he was aware that sometimes other people did it like that:

https://hero.handmade.network/episode/code/day006/#3370

Perhaps he's referencing the thing you watched? In which case it sounds like normally defaults to passing by reference for structs..

Answer (score 0):

If you pass by value you are likely passing via registers (assuming not too many arguments and each one is not too large).  That means the callee doesn't need to do anything to use the values, they are already in registers.  If passing by reference, the address of each value may be in a register, but that requires a dereference which needs to look in the CPU cache (if not main memory), which is slower.

On many popular systems you can pass-by-value roughly 5-10 values which are each as wide as an address.